# 0x8badf00d exception code on iPad running iOS 4.3, but not on iPad or iPhone running iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, exception, ios4

I added a new feature to my medical app to allow users to import E-mail attachments into the app's Document folder for offline viewing. Importing E-mail attachments into the app on an iPad 2 running iOS 5.1 or on an iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1 works perfectly. However, on an original iPad running iOS 4.3, importing an attachment fails to open the app (it hangs before showing the splash screen). The crash log includes the exception code 0x8badf00d and shows that the app quit after trying to launch for 20 seconds. While maintaining iOS 4.x compatibility is not crucial, I would like to continue 4.x support if this issue is resolvable. I wonder if the issue is related to iOS 4, or to the architecture of the original iPad. Any thoughts would be appreciated very much, especially since testing this bug on the simulator seems impossible. Of note, the app launch does not require any network activity other than Apple's Reachability code; typical launch time is almost instantaneous. Thanks.

Comment: Try pausing your app after, say, 10 seconds of trying to launch and seeing where the code is blocked. Alternatively, you could use the Time Profiler instrument or similar to see where the time is going.

Comment: Time Profiler shows (NSFileManager directoryContentsAtPath:matchingExtension:options:keepExtension:error:] If I temporarily comment out the code that renames the imported attachment file and deletes the Inbox folder that the attachment import process creates, then the residual Inbox folder is of size 0 bytes. Seems that there is an error occurring somewhere between the Mail app quitting and my app launching. Again, the error is puzzling, since the process is very quick on a device running iOS 5.x. At this point I am doubting that the relatively slower processor speed of iPad 1 is an issue.

Comment: After trial and error with code substitution, I found that the hang was occurring with this code to convert the attachment file name into a string from its url (works in iOS5, but not iOS4):    NSString *localizedName = nil;
    [url getResourceValue:&localizedName forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:NULL]; Thanks much for your help and for reminding me about the usefulness of Instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the import of new data is taking a long time, you shouldn't be importing the attachment in your application:didFinishLaunching:. You should instead show the user a spinner or similar immediately, and then complete the import process on a background thread.

The other thing to check is to make sure that you don't simply have a mistaken infinite loop, or something else that's calling `directoryContentsAtPath:matchingExtension:options:keepExtension:error` over and over.

Answer (score 1):

The OS is saying it's taking too long to launch. Reduce your launch times.

This is the watch dog timer killing your app, assuming your app is hung. Now it is not surprising why the slowest device was the first to exhibit the problem.